# Echo array after checking tables mysqli

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli, row, echo

**What i need would echo all surveys from the 'surveys' table that do not have a record of completion in the 'completed' table.**
This code works but only checks if a specified single survey was completed or not and echos that 1 specific survey. If you look at the code, first it checks if a completion record exist for survey id 1 and if not it echos survey id 1. I want it to echo all the surveys that do not have completion records by the the logged in user.

```
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    $completed1 = mysqli_query($con1,"SELECT * FROM completed WHERE surveyid = '1' AND userid = '$id'");
    $survey1 = mysqli_query($con1,"SELECT * FROM surveys WHERE id = '1'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($completed1)>0){
     echo "Survey completed!";
    }
    elseif(mysqli_num_rows($survey1)>0){
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($survey1))
      echo $row["title"];
     }
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con1))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: may be this `$_SESSION['id'] = $id;` should be `$id=$_SESSION['id'];`, i don't see any reason that it should be like this `$_SESSION['id'] = $id;` but i see the reason that it should be like `$id=$_SESSION['id'];` because in your query where clause `userid = '$id'`

Comment: I'm trying to check what surveys are complete and echo all incomplete surveys, this code works but i'm trying to make it echo more than just one incomplete survey.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Query should return all rows with incomplete surveys and put them into an array.
Then do a foreach to echo out all incomplete surveys.

For example, SQL query should be something like:

```
SELECT is_complete FROM surveys WHERE is_complete = 0;
```

Instead of adding a table with "completed" surveys, just add a column to the surveys table that says "is_complete" ... if it's 0 it's not complete, if it's 1 its complete.

As far as the PHP goes, it would be something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT title FROM surveys WHERE is_complete = 0";
$stmt = $con1->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$surveys = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_NUM);

foreach ($surveys as $survey) {
    echo $survey[0];
}
```

Hope this helps and gets you pointed to the right direction!

Comment: I can't add a column to the surveys table that "is_complete" because multiple users can fill out the survey, not just 1. Using a column to determine if the survey is completed would only work if 1 user was completing it.